# Intermittent power to stove

Tags: electrical

My stove/oven will not stay on.  Keeps turning on and off or erroring with a Power Failure error code.  I had an electrician here.  He put a meter and checked both the breaker and the outlet.  Stated itbis probably on the supply line and to call my Power Utility Company. I did that everything tested okay.  I still don't have a functional stove.  The stove is brand new out of the box was working this morning.

Comment: Is there *any* other problem in the house wiring? Toaster taking longer than normal, other appliances having PF, appliances burning out unexpectedly, etc.? Do you own a voltmeter?  I sense United States/Canada and not NYC, can you confirm?

Comment: What make and model is said stove, and are there any other appliances with issues?

Comment: New stove , electrician said power is good, power company said power is good, why do you think it is a power issue? Sounds like a faulty connection in the stove.